# How do I know what replacement algorithm the linux server uses?

Tags: linux, cache

I am doing some experiments on the replacement algorithm. How do I know what replacement algorithm is used in the L1 cache on my Linux server? And how do I set up L1 Cache to use random replacement algorithm?

It seems that the replacement strategy of the real machine cannot be modified. It can only be modified on the simulator. Thanks,everyone.

I just learned that the replacement algorithm is fixed at the hardware level and cannot be modified. Therefore, different replacement algorithms can only be simulated on the simulator.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: The L1 cache replacement policy is defined by the hardware, so the place to look for info on this is the CPU documentation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's related to hardware rather than to the OS running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of them use `plru` and `tlru`. Some use `random replacement algorithms`. You can write some code for a simple test. Or check the CPU manual.